# Why is the int in the Font constructor not changing the font size while painting the string?

Tags: java, fonts, awt, graphics2d

My problem is where you see the Font constructor, the last term is the font size integer, and whether it says 12 or 100(like now) it still prints the text at the same size. What am I doing wrong.

```
@Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        Font font = new Font(Font.SERIF, Font.PLAIN, 100);

        if(setTextAttributes){
            setTextAttributes();
            setTextAttributes = false;
        }

        c.paintCursor( g2d );

        font = font.deriveFont(map);
        g2d.setFont(font);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
                             RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_OFF);
        g2d.drawString(text, lineX, lineY);

    }
```

Comment: What is "map" here? Does it by any chance contain an entry for size? Try getting rid of the `deriveFont` call.

Comment: @JonSkeet 
    private static Map<TextAttribute, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

Comment: That is where I implement my text attributes like superscript.. so on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line `font.deriveFont(map)` creates new font as it's said in [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#deriveFont%28java.util.Map%29)